# Robot Framework errors when running my maven-selenium-testNG java project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, robotframework

I'm trying to set up a java project that uses Maven, Selenium 3 and TestNG in Eclipse. I did it successfully by creating a maven project and just adding selenium and testNG dependencies, then letting maven to do all the work of downloading libraries.

But now I want to add Robot Framework, so I grabbed the dependency info from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.robotframework/robotframework/3.0.2 and plugin info, then created a "robotframework/acceptance" folder within src/test and a tests.robot file in src/test/robotframework/acceptance to write my tests (I only added an example test that opens a website, just to check if it works).

This is what my pom.xml looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.automation</groupId>
  <artifactId>automated_tests</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>robotframework</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>  
</project>
```

And this is my test:

```
*** Settings ***
Library                             SeleniumLibrary
Test Set Up                         Start Selenium Server
Test Tear Down                      Stop Selenium Server

*** Test Cases ***
Visit google
  Open Browser  https://www.google.com  chrome
  Close Browser
```

I also created a run configuration like this:

1. In the Run Configurations dialog, double clicked on the Maven Build
2. Clicked on the Browser Workspace button and selected my project as the base directory
3. Under "Goals" I entered robotframework:run
4. Checked "Resolve Workspace artifacts" and "Update Snapshots"

However, when I run it using this, I get the following error:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\myself\automated_tests\src\test\robotframework\acceptance\tests.robot': Importing test library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: ImportError: No module named SeleniumLibrary
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\Users\myself\.m2\repository\org\robotframework\robotframework\3.0.2\Lib
  C:\Users\myself\.m2\repository\org\robotframework\robotframework\3.0.2\robotframework-3.0.2.jar\Lib
  __classpath__
  __pyclasspath__/
CLASSPATH:
  /C:/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.6.3.20160209-1444/jars/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar
Acceptance.Tests :: A resource file containing the application specific key...
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: The first thing I suggest is to stop using SeleniumLibrary. That is a very old library which has been replaced by Selenium2Library. Note for people in the future: sometime in 2017 there will be a renaming event where SeleniumLibrary will be renamed to something else, and Selenium2Library will be renamed to SeleniumLibrary. At the time I write this, however, SeleniumLibrary has been deprecated in favor of Selenium2Library.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I was following some old tutorial I found, but I actually was trying to use selenium 3 (as that's my maven dependency). If I remove the whole `Settings` part of my test (as the server doesn't need to be started anymore with selenium 3), I don't get the errors anymore. But still, I get errors like `No keyword with name 'Open Browser' found.` It's like robot is not finding the default keywords implementation...

Comment: You have to import the Selenium2Library. If you removed the whole `Settings` section, then robot isn't going to find the Selenium2Library keywords. You must import that library.

Comment: But if I import Selenium2Library in my test I still get `[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\mypath\src\test\robotframework\acceptance\tests.robot': Importing test library 'Selenium2Library' failed: ImportError: No module named Selenium2Library`. Aren't the pom robotframework dependency and robotframework-maven-plugin in my pom.xml enough to have the library installed? Am I missing some other dependency or plugin in pom.xml?

Comment: I don't know anything about maven. I just know that to use selenium2library keywords, you must import that library in your test.